# $.get error calling ASP.NET 5 WebAPI Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I get a $.get error calling my WebAPI Controller. The data sent by the $.get still gets to the Controller's method and sends back the data but I get no return value.

HTML Page:

```
function GetById() {
    var key = $("#KeyList").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    $.get("/api/todo/id", { key: key }, function (data) {
        $("#KeyLabel").html(data.Name);
    })
    .error(alert("error"));
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
    public ActionResult GetById(string key)
    {
        var item = TodoItems.Find(key);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

Comment: Care to share the error?  Fairly sure we can't help much without that info.

Comment: Update: I only get the error when using an ASP.NET 5 WebAPI project Controller, not an ASP.NET 5 MVC project WebAPI Controller, if that helps. Standard Visual Studio 2015 templates for WebAPI and MVC projects.

Comment: THE ERROR, include the error in your question or NO ONE CAN ANSWER if you don't include the error.  12 hours is about 12 hours longer than it usually takes to get a question answered on SO.  we need to see THE ERROR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, bad coding. This is better, no errors:

```
.error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
})
```